# What test Ruby perform on the `when` clause statement before calling `.===` operator?

Tags: ruby

Ruby uses `===` operator on the `case/when` type execution style.Now It also known that Ruby depending on the type
of the thing present in the `when` clause, calls the respective `.===` method.

Say `when` statement contains the `class` names, then the rule is - `it will use Module#===, which will return true if the right side is an instance of,
or subclass of, the left side.` One example with this context is:

Here `instance of` test occurs

```
obj = 'hello'
#=> "hello"
case obj
when String
print 'It is a string'
when Fixnum
print 'It is a number'
else
print 'It is not a string'
end
#It is a string
#=> nil
```

Here `subclass of` test occurs

```
num = 10
#=> 10
case num
when Numeric
puts "Right class"
else
puts "Wrong class"
end
#Right class
#=> nil
```

Now `when` contains `String` literals then String#=== is called, which in turn checks if left and right handside 
literal are same(same chracter in same sequence) or not.

```
a = "abc"
#=> "abc"
case a
when "def" then p "Hi"
when "abc" then p "found"
else "not found"
end
#"found"
#=> "found"
```

The all logic is too cool. Now my query is with `case/when` structure -

- ***How does ruby know if `when` holding `class`, or `String` literals or
  anything valid at runtime?***

or

- ***What test does it perform before calling the respective `.===`
  operator on the thing `when` holding currently.***

***EDIT***

Before understanding the `Case/when` working principal,let me clear the below which `when` does while it gets its turn.

```
String.===("abc") #=> true
```

Because "abc" is an instance of `String` class. - Am I right?

Now I tried the below just to check who is whose super class.

```
10.class #=> Fixnum
Fixnum.superclass #=> Integer
Integer.superclass #=> Numeric
Numeric.superclass #=> Object
```

Humm. That means the below returns `true` as Fixnum is also the indirect subclass of `Numeric`. - Am I right?

```
Numeric.===(10) #=> true
```

But why then the below outputs contradictory to the above?

```
Numeric.===(Fixnum) #=> false
```

***Trying to be more specific to my query as below :***

When we are calling `Numeric.===(10)` and `String.===("abc")` . I think we are sending not `"abc"` and `10` rather `"abc".class` and `10.class`.

```
10.===(10) #=> true
Numeric.===(10) #=> true
```

Now look at the above. Both return `true`. Does they output `true` on the same logic? I think `NO`. `10.===(10)` is just like
`10 ==(10)` comparison. But `Numeric.===(10)` outputs `true` as class of `10` is the subclass of `Numeric`.

```
"abc".===("abc") #=> true
String.===("abc") #=> true
```

Now look at the above. Both return `true`. Does they output `true` on the same logic? I think `NO`. `"abc".===("abc")` is just like simple string literal comparison `"abc" ==("abc")` comparison. But `String.===("abc")` outputs `true` as `"abc"` which is an instance of `String`.

Now my question is how ruby detects lefthand side operands types and apply the proper rule of comparisons ?

I might be 100% wrong, In that case please correct me.

Comment: If the `===` method is not overridden in a class it will just use the orignal `Module#===`

Comment: Nothing I override as above examples suggest. I just wanted to know the plain behavior.

Comment: That's what I mean, `String#===` just overrides `Module#===`. Your case/when is really just calling `#===` on the object.

Comment: @LeeJarvis I just updated my description. tried to be more specific to my question. Let me know if you have any confusion to understand what I am asking for.

Comment: @LeeJarvis: `String` doesn't inherit from `Module`, there's no way it could override `Module#===`. It *does* inherit from `Object` and override `Object#===`, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain what @Lee Jarvis also explaines.

```
class Someclass
end

s = Someclass.new
p s.methods.sort
#[:!, :!=, :!~, :<=>, :==, :===, :=~, :__id__, :__send__, :class, :clone,(...)
```

Look at the 5th method. My Someclass instance has a `===`method out of nowhere.

Actually, it has 56 methods and I did not define one of them. They are inherited from Object; every class in Ruby inherits from Object. For class Object (and my Someclass), #=== is effectively the same as calling #==, but (as the docs say) #=== is typically overwritten by descendants to provide meaningful semantics in case statements.

So ruby does nothing smart, it just sends the object in question a `===` message (or calls the `===`method if you prefer that).

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is how ruby detects lefthand side operands types and apply the proper rule of comparisons ?

It doesn't. It simply calls the `===` method. That's it. That's just how object-orientation works, and it is nothing specific to Ruby, *every* OO language works the same way: you call a method on an object, and the object decides how to react. (Or, in a class-based language like Ruby, PHP, Java, C#, C++, Python etc. the *class* of the object decides.)

Different objects may react in different ways. Classes check whether the argument is an instance of themselves, Regexps check whether the argument is matched by them, Ranges check whether the argument is covered by them.

It's just basic method dispatch.

Comment: As usual you are great! `+1` to you. :) But look here [What Type?](http://ruby.about.com/od/control/a/The-Case-Statement.htm) - which made me too confused. Any suggestions what he meant there?

Comment: Could you look into my [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211827/confusion-with-the-order-of-execution-when-next-with-unless-in-ruby) ? Your explanation is best to me as always.

Comment: There's no difference between that usage of `case` and any other. `Module#===` just happens to be defined to check whether the argument is an instance of `self`, just like `Regexp#===` happens to be defined to check whether the argument is matched by `self`. I'm not too happy with that tutorial. It starts off with the title "The Case Statement": in Ruby, `case` isn't a statement, it's an expression. In fact, there *are no* statements in Ruby, *everything* is an expression. The author even demonstrates that in the last section "Case Assignment". And in the section "What Type", he is testing …

Comment: … what *class* or *module* the value belongs to, not what *type*. That's *very* different.

Comment: Humm.. Now I am bit confident on this. Actually I that article made me hard to think about the whole post. And to find and understand his `what Type` section I did too mane experiments as I posted in my post. :( But now I am trying to flush out all the things what I learned from that tutorial about this topic. It created too many confusion in my mind. Thanks Jorg for any such conceptual issue, is there anyway to reach to you without `SO`?